# What happened if I choose different branch to merge with Git in Android Studio 3.3.4?

Tags: git, android-studio

I use Git in my Android Studio project, the current local branch is `Test_A`, and the remote branchs are `origin/Test_A` and `orgin/master`.

1: What happened if I choose different branch to merge when I launch *Pull* operation? just like *1.png*, *2.png* and *3.png*?

2: It seem that the branch `Test_A` map to `origin/Test_A` and `master` map to `orgin/master` from *branch.png*, right?

**1.png**

[image]

**2.png**

[image]

**3.png**

[image]

**branch.png**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: What happened if I choose different branch to merge when I launch
>   Pull operation? just like 1.png, 2.png and 3.png?

In first case the changes from remote `Test_A` are fetched & merged with local `Test_A`.

In second case changes from remote `master` are fetched and:
1.local `master` is updated. 2.local `Test_A` is merged with local `master` on `Test_A` branch.

In third case:
1. Changes from remote `Test_A` are fetched and merged into local `Test_A` branch.
2. Changes from remote `master` are fetched and merged into local `master` branch.
3. Local `Test_A` branch is merged with local `master` branch on `Test_A` branch.

In all the cases your merged code is not pushed to remote branches at all. Also when I say `Local Test_A branch is merged with local master branch on Test_A branch` it means after merging code on `Test_A` & `master` the code resides on local `Test_A`.

> 2: It seem that the branch Test_A map to origin/Test_A and master map
>   to orgin/master from branch.png, right?

Correct. Any local branch `abc_xyz` will be mapped to `origin/abc_xyz`. When you clone a repository and want to switch to the branch `origin/abc_xyz` you have to use `git checkout abc_xyz` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Merge = collect all current code from 2 [Test_A and Master] branch to Test_A so your code and your feature in master will appear in Tast_A too.

tip: I recommend to use GitKraken to see what happen easied with a graph

Answer (score 0):

1. The selected remote branch(`origin/xxx`) is updated.
2. The updated remote branch is merged to the current branch.

No matter what the current branch is, the selected branch is to be merged. The merge may fail due to conflicts or the remote branch being behind or up-to-date with the current branch. When multiple branches are selected, an octopus merge could happen. To merge the mapping branch or another branch or other branches depends on the workflow.

Comment: Thanks! I launch Pull operation, "1. The selected remote branch(`origin/xxx`) is updated", why is the  selected remote branch updated?

Comment: @HelloCW If the repository is successfully cloned, there should be a config item like `remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. `git pull` is equivalent to `git fetch && git merge` or `git fetch && git rebase`. This item instructs `git fetch` to retrieve the branch `foo` or `refs/heads/foo` from the remote repository `origin` and updates the remote tracking branch `origin/foo` or `refs/remotes/origin/foo` in the local repository.

Comment: Thanks! I mean that local  branch will change but remote branch will not change when I launch Pull operation, right?